# understanding std::find_if() using a lamda on std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, find, std

It is my understanding that `std::find_if() below` returns an iterator to the first element in the range of `arg` for which the third argument (lamda function) returns true. Is that correct?

Could somebody explain why there isn't an iterator defined like this `std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>::iterator = std::find_if(...)`?

Where is the iterator returned by `std::find_if()` stored and how can you call `->second` on its own and not on an iterator?

```
std::type_index argType(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::pair<std::string, std::type_index> arg)->bool
        {
            return arg.first == name;
        }
    )->second;
}
```

Comment: Count the parentheses again. `->second` dereferences the iterator returned by `std::find_if`, which points to a pair, and accesses the `second` member of said pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is my understanding that `std::find_if()` below returns an iterator

Yes, but that iterator is then dereferenced within the same expression. The function returns a *copy* of the `std::type_index` from some element of `args_`, which is presumably some std-like container with a `value_type` of `std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>` (or similar).

At a guess it's a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>>`, because if it were a map the whole function could be simplified to

```
return args_.at(name);
```

> Could somebody explain why there isn't an iterator defined like this `std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>::iterator = std::find_if(...)`?

Well firstly `std::pair` doesn't have a member `iterator`. I assume you meant `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>>::iterator` (or whichever collection type `args_` is).

There doesn't need to be a separate statement declaring such an iterator, in much the same way as you don't need a separate `double` in the statement

```
return floor(3.14 * radius);
```

when you want an integer circumference calculation.

> Where is the iterator returned by `std::find_if()` stored

Anywhere the compiler likes. It only exists while the return statement is being evaluated.

> how can you call `->second` on its own

You aren't. You are calling it on the temporary returned by `std::find_if`

> and why is there a `!= args_.end()` after the closing brace of `std::find_if`?

There isn't. The author **assumes** that they will find a matching element. If they don't, the program has undefined behaviour. That may be intentional, or it may be a bug.